# How to get the value of a select option, and use it to query an array, to populate another input

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb, ejs

How can I use the value of a select input option, generated by a `forEach` loop, to get the value of another property in the same array object, and set it as the value of another input?

Sorry if that is wordy or its already been answered somewhere, but I cant find the answer and I have been banging my head all day (also this is my first question on SO, so please bear with me).

I have a page in a tuition scheduling app. 
After querying the database on server, I pass in an array of students to the page.
The students in the array have various properties, the ones relevant to this case are id, name and postcode.

```
students = [
    {id: 1, name: 'test1', postcode: 'AB1 1CD'},
    {id: 2, name: 'test2', postcode: 'AB2 2CD'},
    {id: 3, name: 'test3', postcode: 'AB3 3CD'}
]
```

On the scheduling page I have a form for creating a new lesson.
On the form there are 2 inputs. 
First input is a select list to choose a student from the array.
Second input is a text field for the students postcode. 
The options in the select are generated by a `forEach` loop, which loops through the array of students, displays the names, and sets the value of each option to be the students id. (I need the value to remain id)

```
<select name="student" id="studentInput">
    <% students.forEach(function(student){ %>
        <option value="<%=student.id%>"> <%=student.name%> </option>
    <% }); %>
</select>
```

I also need to get the postcode from the student in the array and populate the postcode text field. This is where I am stumped.

```
<input type="text" id="postcodeInput" name="postcode">
```

I used jQuery to get the id from the option when it is changed, and I can populate the postcode field with the id (as a test), which works fine.

```
<script>
    $(document).on("change", "#studentInput", function() {
        var idVariable = $(this).val()
        $("#postcodeInput").val(idVariable);
    });
</script>
```

The above code gives me the student.id value as a string in the postcode field, whereas I need student.postcode

I tried the below code which sets the var `found` as the student corresponding to `id === 3`

```
<% found = student.find(item => item.id === "3"); %>
`
```

Which allows me to set the input value as `found.postcode`

```
<input type="text" id="postcodeInput" name="postcode" value="<%=found.postcode%>">
`
```

This gives me the postcode 'AB3 3CD' as the text field value. Perfect.

But this is with a hardcoded id. How do I make that bit dynamic?

I tried using jQuery, but I cant seem to access the array floating in the html, from within the script tags. 
Either it is not accessible, or I am missing a trick.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

```js
students = [
    {id: 1, name: 'test1', postcode: 'AB1 1CD'},
    {id: 2, name: 'test2', postcode: 'AB2 2CD'},
    {id: 3, name: 'test3', postcode: 'AB3 3CD'}
];

$(document).on("change", "#studentInput", function() {
    var idVariable = $(this).val()
    $("#postcodeInput").val(idVariable);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="student" id="studentInput">
    <% students.forEach(function(student){ %>
        <option value="1"> test1 </option>
        <option value="2"> test2 </option>
        <option value="3"> test3 </option>
    <% }); %>
</select>

<input type="text" id="postcodeInput" name="postcode" value="">
```

Comment: nicely written, but a *snippet* or *fiddle* would have made it easier :)

Comment: It's not clear what you want to make dynamic or what you want where.

Comment: I want to make the id where it says "3" dynamic 
<% found = student.find(item => item.id === "3"); %>

By using the idVariable from the jQuery inside the script tag. Im struggling to get the value of idVariable into the find() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you don't have your `postcode` values stored somewhere in your ejs file, so you cant access these values.
One solution is to save the rendered `students` array in a javascript object, in order to be able to access its values. How to do this?
First in your controller you have to render a new array as JSON string like this.

```
res.render("someEjs", { students: students, jsonStudents: JSON.stringify(students)});
```

Then in your ejs file you can store the json array in a js variable like this:

```
var students = JSON.parse('<%- jsonStudents %>');
```

Now with javascript or jquery code you have access to `postcode` values. For example:

```
$(document).on("change", "#studentInput", function() {
    var idVariable = $(this).val()
    var postCodeVal;
    for (var x of students) {
        if (x.id === idVariable) {
            postCodeVal = x.postcode;
        }
     }
    $("#postcodeInput").val(postCodeVal);
});
```

I am not sure if this is exactly what you want, but i think i gave you an idea.

Comment: So currently I have the student array being passed in by the controller. But not as JSON I think. I will give this a try and report back.

Comment: That worked beautifully! Thank you so much. All I had to do was pass the array in as JSON, to be able to access it in the jquery code.